# Angular POST to MariaDB with nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, typescript, mariadb

I am using template that a former colleague created, and that template only reads data from database via GET API.

Now, I am trying to find a way to post new data to database (e.g. via POST API).

I am using MySQL and MariaDB in python, and eventually I need to call python function from Angular so I am sticking to MySQL and MariaDB in Angular as well.

Using a template that my colleague created, I have changed from GET API to POST API like in the following:

**Ctrl.ts**

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import conn from './config/mariadb';

async function setAmnt(req: Request, res: Response) {
   const { amntArray } = req.query;

   conn.query("INSERT INTO table_name (columns) VALUES (amntArray[0], ...)", function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) {
         throw error;
      }
      return res.json({results});
   });
}

export {
   setAmnt
};
```

**Service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class APIService {
   constructor(
      private httpClient: HttpClient
   ) {}

   public setAmnt(amntArray): Observable<any> {
      return Observable.create(observer => {
         this.httpClient
         .post(`localhost:3000/some/address`, amntArray)
         .subscribe(
            (data:any) => {
               observer.next(data);
               observer.complete();
            },
            err => observer.error(err)
         );
      });
   }
}
```

**Route.ts**

```
import express from 'express';
import { setAmnt } from 'Ctrl';

const router = express.Router();

router
   .route('/some/address')
   .get(setAmnt);

export default router;
```

**Main.ts**

```
export class SomeClass implements OnInit {
   constructor(
      private APIService: Service
   ) {}

   ngOnInit() {
      // some code
   }

   clicked() {
      const amntArray = [date, amnt, ...]; // all variables defined in Main.ts
      APIService.setAmnt(amntArray);
   }
```

**Main.html**

```
<Button
   (click)="clicked()">Click Here</Button>
```

As you can see, there is an error-catching code in Ctrl.ts AND Service.ts, but both give no error when I compile this code and click the button. Everything goes smooth, except that it does not write to database.

I am just searching on the Internet as I go along, so I have not that deep knowledge, though I know that Angular cannot directly communicate with DB, so it has to go through node.

So, if anyone could point out any mistake or guide me toward the right path from here, I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

**In post request data will be received in req.body Not in req.query ....**
hope this will work i dont know about raw queries

```
// change Api from get to post
router
   .route('/some/address')
   .post(setAmnt);
```

```
async function setAmnt(req: Request, res: Response) {
   // we use req.body in post method
   const { amntArray } = req.body;

   conn.query("INSERT INTO table_name (columns) VALUES (amntArray[0], ...)", function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) {
         throw error;
      }
      return res.json({results});
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited my code like the way you suggested, but still nothing happens. No errors, but still no writing in DB. Just one question, though. Inside async function, if I put console.log(), is that supposed to not print anything? I wanted to see if async function works, so I put in console.log() in it, but it did not print.

Comment: it should print inside async function ... 
console.log(req.body) 
and check what is the incoming data from post api call

Comment: I just confirmed that console.log inside async function did print IN GET API, but NOT IN POST API. So, I am guessing that POST API is not called at all?

Comment: yes in this case Your post api is not calling properly

Comment: Got it. I will work from there. If you have any other ideas why post api is not called properly, please let me know. Thanks for your help.

Comment: please share your service.ts of get request which is working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221140/discussion-between-muhammad-fazeel-and-beginnercoder).